# Does shallow-cloning extend also the modifier of properties in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Let's say we have a class like:

```
class ExampleOject {
   readonly readOnlyProperty = 'HttpErrorResponse';
   otherProperty: string;
}
```

Is it allowed to do the following operation:

```
let clonedObj = { ...obj1 }; // while obj1 is an instance of type ExampleOject 
clonedObj.readOnlyProperty = 'Other Value';
```

In other words: Does shallow-cloning extend also the modifier of properties in Typescript? So, is `clonedObj.readOnlyProperty` also `readonly` and shouldn't be modified?

My IDE (Webstorm) shows me `TS2540`. But I can compile this code.

Answer (score 1):

TS eventually will compile to JS and we don't have `readonly` fields and static types in JS. Your code will be compiled to:

```
"use strict";
class ExampleOject {
    constructor() {
        this.readOnlyProperty = 'HttpErrorResponse';
        otherProperty: string;
    }
}
const obj1 = {};
let clonedObj = Object.assign({}, obj1); // while obj1 is an instance of type ExampleOject 
clonedObj.readOnlyProperty = 'Other Value';
```